# Java - Why does append F to `float a=0.32F` tell it to store 32-bit float in a, but doing `float a = 0.32` tell it you want to store 64 bit double?

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment, literals, identifier

I'm working through "Beginning Java Programming" by Bart Baesens, Aimee Backiel, and Steppe vanden Broucke.

And I'm talking about the difference between appending and not appending a letter when assigning a literal to an identifier. Ex:

`float ratio = 0.234`

compared to:

`float ratio = 0.234F`

On the page I'm looking at (and I can't see clarification anywhere else in the book) it's not helpful at all.

Googling results in many not-so-clear answers. I did find the following answer on Quora:

"
*When the interpreter sees `float ratio = 0.234;` 
it knows what float means because its a reserved keyword 
it infers that ratio is an identifier
= is an assignment operator 
0.234 is a double literal and 
; is a delimiter
because that's just how the language has been defined. So the statement is syntactically correct but when the semantic check begins it sees that you are trying to store a 64-bit double literal into a 32-bit float variable which will lead to loss in precision so it will give you an error or a warning.* 
"

But why would doing `float ratio = 0.234` make it think I want to assign a 64-bit double literal into a 32-bit float variable? I mean. I'm literally telling it that I want a float, so there must be another reason that I'm missing.

Comment: `0.234F` is a `float` literal, `0.234` is a `double` literal. `234` is an `int` literal, `234L` is a `long` literal. For better or worse, hat's just the way things are...

Comment: what do you think the difference between `double d = 0.234;` and `float f = 0.234;` is?  Do you think they are the same?

Comment: May help to go through this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 32/64 discussion here relates to the literal, not the variable.
`0.234F` is a 32bit float literal, while `0.234` is a 64bit double literal.

So if we reexamine those two statements:

`float ratio = 0.234F` means "take the 32bit float value of 0.234 and place it in the variable `ratio`".
`float ratio = 0.234` means "take the 64bit double value of 0.234 and place it in the variable `ratio`" - which, as you've seen, is not possible and results in a compilation error.

Comment: Thank-you, this is a good, concise and clear response. 
But it does seem weird to me. I'm new to programming so perhaps it's my lack of knowledge... but it seems to me that if I have `float ratio = 0.234` the language should be designed to look at the type of the variable to determine what the literal is. 
But I'm sure there is some reason for that, which I don't know yet

Comment: @JackW it's the other way around - literals have types regardless of their context. `0.234` is a `double` just like `"hello world"` is a string. In the cases that an implicit (widening) conversion is possible, Java will implicitly do it for you (e.g., `long mylong = 123;`). In the cases it isn't, it would error out. This is Java's way of saying "hey, you're trying to assign a 64 bit double to a 32 bit float, and might lose some precision. Are you **sure** you want to do that?"

Comment: OK, it's definitely clearling up for me then. 
So would you recommend that I always append those letters whenever I'm assigning a literal to an identifier?
Like, for example, should I *always* do `float a = 0.334F` (and similarly to the other types)?

Comment: @JackW yes. Note that `int` literals have no suffixes, and `double` literals have an optional `D`, which most people don't usually use.

Comment: thanks again. I think I have a good handle on it now

Answer (score 2):

A floating point literal without a prefix is interpreted as a 64-bit `double` literal. That's the way the Java language is defined. Trying to store a `double` literal in a `float` variable is not allowed (since it might require a type conversion that loses precision).

`0.234` may seem to you like a value that can be stored in a `float` variable, but the compiler interprets it as a 64-bit value, so trying to store it in a 32-bit variable requires a conversion that may lose precision.

When you add the `f` (or `F`) suffix to the floating point literal, the compiler knows it should be interpreted as a 32-bit value, which can be stored in a `float` variable.

Comment: So essentially, it's just the way Java works and I'm not missing something? Like, 0.234 will always be considered a double when you are assigning it to something unless you append one of the letters that tells it what it should be?

Comment: @JackW it will be double unless you append the f/F suffix or explicitly cast it to `float` (i.e. `float x = (float) 0.234;`)

Comment: thank-you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A `double` uses more space than `float` in Java. Doubles need 64-bit storage compared to 32-bit storage of float data type.

By default, floating point numbers are double in Java.

For example: 
if you type `float y = 394.04;` into your ide an IDE it will tell you that you can't assign 394.04 to a float, this is because it is a double literal.

To explicitly cast this to a float you may add `f` as a suffix. for example `float y = 394.04f`

A `double` data type is more precise than float. A double variable can provide precision up to 15 to 16 decimal points as compared to float precision of 6 to 7 decimal digits to do this it requires more space in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler do two things when parse language first syntax check and second semantic check.
let us consider `ratio = 0.234;` in that variable is ratio `=` is assignment and `0.234` is type double which is 64-bit and finally `;` is delimiter but for `ratio = 0.234F` semantic check happen try to store 64 in 32 bit.